# Get ascending/descending by a variable with ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have a list of users that I want to sort by name. The list would look like this:

```
const data = [
  { id: 2, name: 'Asterios' },
  { id: 1, name: 'Alex' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Tim' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Sadie' },
]
```

I have implemented a relatively simple selector which will sort the list of users based on some property.

```
const getUserList = createSelector(
  getUsers,
  getSortBy,
  getSortOrder,
  (users, sortBy, sortOrder) => R.sortWith([
    R.ascend(R.prop(sortBy)),
  ])(users),
);
```

However, I want to take the variable `sortOrder`, which can be either `'ASC'` or `'DESC'`, and apply that sort order.

I tried something like this:

```
const sortDirection = R.ifElse(R.equals('DESC'), descend, ascend);

sortWith([ compose(sortDirection(sortOrder), prop('name')), ])
```

Is there a good way to apply this ascending/descending sorting logic via a variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, you have several minor problems here.  It's often easier to debug one big problem, though, than several small ones.

### Using `ifElse` properly

The first one is the use of `ifElse`.  This takes three functions as parameters, and returns a new function which, depending on the result of calling the first one with your arguments, **calls** either the second or third function with those arguments.  Note that it doesn't return the function; it calls it.  There are several ways to fix this.  You could wrap those functions with `always`:

```
const sortDirection = R.ifElse(R.equals('DESC'), always(descend), always(ascend))
```

But I think it's simpler to forgo point-free and use

```
const sortDirection = dir => (dir === 'DESC' ? descend : ascend)
```

### Understanding `compose`

Second, you're passing a slightly wrong value into `ascend` or `descend`.  Although this isn't quite the implementation, think of `ascend` as something like

```
const ascend = curry(fn, a, b) => fn(a) < fn(b) ? -1 : fn(a) > fn(b) ? 1 : 0);
```

Note that if you pass a unary function to this, such as `fn = prop('name')`, you get back `(a, b) => fn(a) < fn(b) ? -1 : fn(a) > fn(b) ? 1 : 0`, which is a binary comparator function.  `sortWith` accepts a list of comparators. So this would be fine.

But if your `sortOrder` is `'ASC'`, then this

```
sortWith([ compose(sortDirection(sortOrder), prop('name')), ])
```

becomes

```
sortWith([ compose(ascend, prop('name')) ])
```

which is equivalent to

```
sortWith([ x => ascend(prop('name')(x)) ])
```

And the function passed to the sorter is not a proper comparator.  It is a unary function.  The problem is that `prop('name')` is a unary function, so the `compose` doesn't do quite what you were hoping.

If you were to rearrange slightly, you could get the correct behavior:

```
sortWith([ compose(sortDirection(sortOrder), prop)('name'), ], )
```

this converts, first with `ASC`, to

```
sortWith([ compose(ascend, prop)('name'), ], )
```

and thus to

```
sortWith([ (x => ascend(prop(x)))('name'), ], )
```

which is

```
sortWith([ ascend(prop('name')), ], )
```

And as we saw, `ascend(fn)` is a binary comparator.

### Putting it together

So one way to fix your issues is with

```
const sortDirection = R.ifElse(R.equals('DESC'), always(descend), always(ascend))
const sortOrder = 'DESC'
sortWith([ compose(sortDirection(sortOrder), prop)('name'), ], data)
//=> [{.. Tim}, {.. Sadie}, {.. Asterios}, {.. Alex}]
```

And of course if `sortOrder = 'ASC'`, then

```
sortWith([ compose(sortDirection(sortOrder), prop)('name'), ], data)
//=> [{.. Alex}, {.. Asterios}, {.. Sadie}, {.. Tim}]
```

### Alternate approach

There are two things I still really don't like about the above:

1. It uses the free variable `sortOrder`.  I would prefer that such variables were parameters to my functions.
2. It uses `sortWith` rather than `sort`.  `sortWith` is a way to *combine* comparator functions.  Since we have only one, `sort` is simpler.

Here's how I might write it to solve those problems:

```js
const {ascend, descend, prop, sort} = R
const data = [{ id: 2, name: 'Asterios' }, { id: 1, name: 'Alex' }, { id: 4, name: 'Tim' }, { id: 3, name: 'Sadie' }]

const sorter = dir => (dir === 'DESC' ? descend : ascend)(prop('name'))

console.log(sort(sorter('DESC'), data))
//=> [{.. Tim}, {.. Sadie}, {.. Asterios}, {.. Alex}]
console.log(sort(sorter('ASC'), data))
//=> [{.. Alex}, {.. Asterios}, {.. Sadie}, {.. Tim}]
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't use Ramda but hopefully it gives you an idea on how to start working through the problem

```js
const ascComparator = (a, b) =>
  a < b
    ? -1
    : a > b
      ? 1
      : 0

const descComparator = (a, b) =>
  ascComparator (b, a)

const data =
  [ { id: 2, name: 'Asterios' }
  , { id: 1, name: 'Alex' }
  , { id: 4, name: 'Tim' }
  , { id: 3, name: 'Sadie' }
  ]

data.sort ((a,b) => ascComparator (a.name, b.name))

console.log (data)
// Alex, Asterios, Sadie, Tim

data.sort ((a,b) => descComparator (a.name, b.name))
  
console.log (data)
// Tim, Sadie, Asterios, Alex
```

The program above demonstrates a beautiful use case for `contramap`

```js
const contramap = (f, g) =>
  (a, b) =>
    f (g (a), g (b))

const prop = k => o =>
  o [k]

const ascComparator = (a, b) =>
  a < b
    ? -1
    : a > b
      ? 1
      : 0

const descComparator = (a, b) =>
  ascComparator (b, a)

const data =
  [ { id: 2, name: 'Asterios' }
  , { id: 1, name: 'Alex' }
  , { id: 4, name: 'Tim' }
  , { id: 3, name: 'Sadie' }
  ]

data.sort (contramap (ascComparator, prop ('name')))

console.log (data)
// Alex, Asterios, Sadie, Tim

data.sort (contramap (descComparator, prop ('name')))
  
console.log (data)
// Tim, Sadie, Asterios, Alex
```

`localeCompare` also works

```
const ascComparator = (a, b) =>
  a.localeCompare (b)

const descComparator = (a, b) =>
  ascComparator (b, a)
```

Comment: Very nice use of contramap!